# Devanagari example with package linguex

Tags: linguistics, linguex

This is an MWE formed with package `linguex`, for having numbered examples. I have also added an English example for the comparison.

```
%!TeX TS-Program=xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\exg. रामः आम्रफलम् खादति\\
राम आंबा खातो\\
राम आंबा खातो.

\exg. This is a sentence.\\
Glossing this sentence here.\\
This is its translation.\\

\end{document}
```

This is the output that I get. First word `राम` (on the second line) is a bit pushed upwards. I don't know why. How to solve this?

[image: 1]

Comment: your font is too large, scale it with the Scale option.

Comment: It improved significantly after changing the scale, but that is a HUGE change in my long document. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Also I have experienced the scale problem with Shobhika nowhere else. It gives finest Devanagari text in available fonts.

Comment: Well the alternative is to enlarge the baselineskip - which isn't quite easy because linguex uses an internal command. Easier would be to use 12pt as class option and then to scale the fonts a bit. Then you have larger baselineskip with smaller fonts.

Comment: I have already written my document with 12pt :(

Comment: I am tempted to use `expex`. It produces good results, but counters are in English